# Is there a way to run the Apple Hardware Test without an optical drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-hardware-test

I have a MacBook Pro 13", Mid-2009 and it came with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard. As I understand it, that means I would have to use the DVDs provided by Apple
to boot into Apple Hardware Test. The problem is I don't have my optical drive anymore since I swapped it out for an extra HDD. How can I run the Apple Hardware Test?

Comment: Did you upgrade to Lion/Mountain Lion ? If yes do you have the recovery partition (press Alt/option at boot chime)

Comment: I just checked and I do have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer [Diagnosis or Hardware Test on a mid 2009 Macbook Pro with MacOS 10.9.2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135687/diagnosis-or-hardware-test-on-a-mid-2009-macbook-pro-with-macos-10-9-2) discusses a GitHub page https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest which has assembled various versions of the AppleHardwareTest which you can download and install in a specific place on your harddisk. This allows you to run the test without a working CRROM.

It worked for me on a Mid 2009 Macpook Pro.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the recovery partition there is a way to do from the partition : [Using Apple Hardware Test (Apple.com)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509)

Just press D at the boot chime.

Comment: Right, I should have said so I already tried and nothings happens. I release D and it boots up like normal

Answer (score 1):

If the model of MacBook Pro that you're using does not support the [Internet version of AHT](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904) and/or does not have an AHT partition on the drive, another Mac that *does* have an optical drive can be used to copy the Applications Install Disc onto other media (including SD cards, USB flash drives, and external hard drives).

Using Disk Utility's "Restore" feature, you can restore the Applications Install Disc that came with your Mac onto an SD card, USB flash drive, or external hard drive. After restoring the DVD image to another disk, you can startup from the AHT partition by holding the "D" key at boot (while that disk is connected).

[image]

Note: this will require you to erase the external drive that you're restoring the Applications Install Disc (AHT) to.

Comment: So basically, I'd have to have the DVD image on a USB?

Comment: Yes, you could image the DVD to an external USB flash drive or hard disk. If you wanted to put the partition onto your internal drive, you may not be able to get AHT to boot. This assumption is based on the fact that the DVD uses the Apple Partition Map, while your startup disk is GPT formatted.

Comment: Or of course you can plug in an external DVD drive if you don't have another Mac sitting around.