# Diagnosis or Hardware Test on a mid 2009 Macbook Pro with MacOS 10.9.2

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I would like to test hardware on a mac book pro model from 2009 with Mac Os X 10.9.2 installed. Since it is running unreliably I would like to perform a diagnosis/hardware test.

What is easy to find on the internet is, that on pre 2013 models, the apple hardware test was to be run, on models after that, the apple diagnosis, see

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781?viewlocale=en_US
- and http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14291

Now I wondered what to do with a macbook that has had its OS version updated (10.9.2 Maverick).

---

I have plainly now  just tried starting the laptop while keeping D pressed multiple times and I never ended up in a AHT or diagnosis mode.

Comment: We would need the Exact model number from your about this mac to proceed. Like this on my Model Identifier: MacBookAir5,2

Answer (score 4):

The *Apple Hardware Test* is included in the installation DVD. Insert it, hold <kbd>D</kbd> and boot from it.

If you don't have the installation DVD at hand, have a look at https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest